# How to convert a string into a mathematical expression in PHP

Tags: php

have stored mathemetical function as string in mySql table. Below is the example.

### Table contains two columns condition and formula.

In condition I have saved as $x <= 10
and in formula I have saved the string as   $x*20

I am getting $x from an input field, now how can I convert the above string so if it meets the condition then it will multiply by 20 and fetch the output.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: You shouldn't store conditions in the format you just provided...

Comment: Thanks for your message but can't see the complete message. can you please explain once again how should keep in the condition column

Comment: @KaustavDey You can see the complete message silkfire didn't write more. You should instead make column containing the comparison type (could contain "smaller", "bigger") and one that contains the number `y` and one column containing the mathematical operation.

Comment: $x is the weight which I am getting from an in put field. $x = $_POST['weight']; so if I can convert the string $x <= 10. Which if($x <= 10) { echo $x * 20; } and 20 is the price so if the condition meets I will get $200 as price. this is what I exactly want

Answer (score 0):

Look like you can use this class :
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/lib/evalmath

for safe evaluation of the formula. 
And by storing you condition like wumm's suggestion, you should be OK.